# Compare two .sdf files in .Net

Tags: .net, sdf

I am working on windows application from where user will be able to get the backup of .sdf file and later user will be able to restore the .sdf file.

Before file restoring file from my .Net application, I want to check whether user has selected valid file (having same database schema).

So if some one has idea to do this then please give suggestion.

Comment: Well, what have you tried yourself? We generally like to see some effort here at Stackoverflow. =)

Comment: Actually I took backup and restore process of sdf, but have no idea to compare schema of database from .net. If some one can give me idea to do this then  please give suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the two databases with SqlCeConnections, then use the [`GetSchema`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection.getschema.aspx) command to retrieve data about table/column structure.  Then you will need to walk through the contents of the tables and make sure all the fields match.

Have you considered using some sort of versioning in your databases with a compatibility list?  For instance, have a table `Version` with a single column/row of the version number in your database, say `VersonNumber`.  Then your application knows that, say, version 1.05 - 1.09 are all compatible with each other, but 1.10 is not, etc.  If that `Version` table is missing completely (or contains an invalid version number), then you automatically know it is not a valid .sdf file for your application.